# JSON.parse преобразует данные?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
$.ajax({
            url: "php/data.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {act: 'load', user: self.user_id},
            success: function (data) {  
                c(data)
                var data = JSON.parse(data);
                c(data)
                self.loader = false;
                self.cols = data;
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

получаю

```
[{"cn":"serial","dt":"varchar","c":""},{"cn":"series","dt":"int","c":""},{"cn":"season","dt":"int","c":""},{"cn":"url","dt":"varchar","c":""}]
    admin.js?1.0:2 
    (4) [Object, Object, Object, Object]
    0:Object
    c
    cn:"serial"
    dt:"int"
```

т.е. varchar каким то образом стал int

js https://gist.github.com/des1roer/2f670631f9a60bbb3ada02a7adfe3742

php https://gist.github.com/des1roer/9ea8067b3d0f6999d3a31b3d47067dcb

Comment: [mcve]? Дай строку с json'ом, на которой получается что-то не то и объясни, почему ты ожидал получить что-то другое.

Comment: https://codepen.io/des1roer/pen/WONjKg?editors=1010

Comment: Все, что относится к вопросу, должно быть в **самом вопросе**. Ссылки могут служить только _дополнением_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `jQuery` парсинг `JSON` делается так с помощью функции `parseJSON()`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "php/data.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {act: 'load', user: self.user_id},
    success: function (data) {  
        .......
        .......
        var json_decode_data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        ........
        ........
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

А это пример парсинга:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' );
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

Comment: при чем тут JQuery? результат тот же самый. вот кст где происходит http://j96177ni.beget.tech/admin/

Comment: @des1roer если так парсинг дает ответ не правильно, значит ваши данные полученные не в формате `JSON`.

Comment: как бы не так https://gist.github.com/des1roer/9ea8067b3d0f6999d3a31b3d47067dcb принудительно делаю json_encode

Comment: @des1roer не знаю как вы сделали пример `github` но я бы дал совет проверить ваш код, после парсинга `JSON` данные не меняются ни как.

Comment: видимо меняются

Comment: @des1roer Для очистки совести задайте в `parseJSON` функцию свою собственно собранную строку `JSON`.

Comment: оно понятно JSON.parse('[{"cn":"serial","dt":"varchar","c":""},{"cn":"series","dt":"int","c":""},{"cn":"season","dt":"int","c":""},{"cn":"url","dt":"varchar","c":""}]') что норм. а почему в моей ситуации такое творится?

Comment: @des1roer Вот я и говорю ищите причину в другой стороне `на серверной части`.

Comment: http://j96177ni.beget.tech/admin/php/data.php?act=load возвращается то верно

Comment: видать хром тупил. сейчас все нормально